# How setattribute value input date?

Tags: javascript, html

#### How would you set the value adding day+1 from the current date in JavaScript?

I have this:

```
   <input type="date" id="mycalendar" >
```

try to set value:

```
    var datedft = document.getElementById('mycalendar').value;

    var date = new Date(datedft);
    var newdate = new Date(date);
    newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate());  
    var dd = newdate.getDate();
    var mm = newdate.getMonth() + 2;
    var y = newdate.getFullYear(); 

    var newformat =y+'-'+mm+'-'+dd ;
    document.getElementById('mycalendar').value = newformat
```

In my console Browser I got:

> The specified value "2020-10-1" does not conform to the required
> format, "yyyy-MM-dd".

Answer (score 1):

The required format is "yyyy-MM-dd", so your date string value should be "2020-10-01".

```
var newFormat = y.toString().padStart(4, '0') + '-' + mm.toString().padStart(2, '0') + '-' + dd.toString().padStart(2, '0');
```

Answer (score 0):

If the date format is absolutely critical to the functioning of the webpage, then we will need to make that choice. Below is a code snippet with the date format altered to the YYYY-MM-DD format.

```
<input type="text" name="input" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" required 
pattern="(?:19|20)\[0-9\]{2}-(?:(?:0\[1-9\]|1\[0-2\])-(?:0\[1-9\]|1\[0-9\]|2\[0-9\])|(?:(?!02)(?:0\[1-9\]|1\[0-2\])-(?:30))|(?:(?:0\[13578\]|1\[02\])-31))" />
```

Comment: hello Top talent, tnks for the answer,  but the problem is not in my input but when I gonna set a new date on input

Comment: :) Here is my anwser.

var dd = ("0" + newdate.getDate()).slice(-2);
var mm = ("0" + (newdate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
var y = newdate.getFullYear(); 

var newformat =y+'-'+mm+'-'+dd; // updated line
document.getElementById('mycalendar').value = newformat

Comment: now with your idea I got : calendario.php:567 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null
I think the problem is when I set the value, I found something like :     document.getElementById('mycalendar').valueAsDate = newformat in internet

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're asking how to get the correct format when the day(getDate()) is less than 10.

```
    var datedft = document.getElementById('mycalendar').value;

    var date = new Date(datedft);
    var newdate = new Date(date);
    newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate());  
    var dd = newdate.getDate();
    var updatedDD = dd >= 10 ? dd : `0${dd}`; // updated line
    var mm = newdate.getMonth() + 2;
    var y = newdate.getFullYear(); 

    var newformat =y+'-'+mm+'-'+updatedDD ; // updated line
    document.getElementById('mycalendar').value = newformat
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to add one day to the date which user has selected. please check the code snippet.

```js
function onChangeDate() {
  var datedft = document.getElementById('mycalendar').value;

  var date = new Date(datedft);
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)
  var newformat = date.toISOString().substr(0, 10)
  document.getElementById('mycalendar').value = newformat
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="mycalendar" onchange='onChangeDate()'>
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code will set the next day date in "mycalendar"

```js
const today = new Date(); // today's date
const tomorrow = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate() + 1)); // tomorrow's date

document.getElementById('mycalendar').value = tomorrow.toISOString().split('T')[0];
```

```html
<input type="date" id="mycalendar" >
```